# Webscraping with Selenium, problems with scraping child pages

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

And trying to **scrape** this website with selenium.

[https://startupbase.com.br/home/startups?q=&states=all&cities=all&segments=Constru%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20Civil~Imobili%C3%A1rio&targets=all&phases=all&models=all&badges=all](https://startupbase.com.br/home/startups?q=&states=all&cities=all&segments=Constru%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20Civil%7EImobili%C3%A1rio&targets=all&phases=all&models=all&badges=all)

What I need: to enter in every child page and extract a lot of information and do this for all the company that is shown.

The code:

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

options = Options()
options.add_argument("window-size=1400,600")
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

ua = UserAgent()
a = ua.random
user_agent = ua.random
print(user_agent)
options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver')

driver.get("https://startupbase.com.br/home/startups?q=&states=all&cities=all&segments=Construção%20Civil~Imobiliário&targets=all&phases=all&models=all&badges=all")

import time

time.sleep(3)

cookies_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'Accept')]")
cookies_button.click()

time.sleep(3)

# Lists that we will iterate to
founder_name = []
name_company = []
site_url = []
local = []
mercado = []
publico_alvo = []
modelo_receita = []
momento = []
sobre = []
fundacao = []
tamanho_time = []
linkedin_company = []
linkedin_founder = []
atualizacao = [] 

while True:
    time.sleep(2)
    html = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    code = soup.prettify()
    print(code)

    containers = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "search-body__item"})

    for container in containers:
         internal_page = container.find('a', href=True)
```

The is still in the beginning because I'm trying to enter into the child pages and I can't that.

I've already tried:

```
internal_page = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/app-root/ng-component/app-layout/div/div/div/div/div/app-layout-column/ng-component/div/ais-instantsearch/div/div/div/div[2]/section/ais-infinite-hits/div/div[2]/a")
internal_page.click()
```

Could someone give a light, please?

Comment: `/html/body/app-root/ng-component/app-layout/div/div/div/div/div/app-layout-column/ng-component/div/ais-instantsearch/div/div/div/div[2]/section/ais-infinite-hits/div/div[2]/a` seems to be wrong. If you got to Chrome devtools and search for this in the elements pane it is a teal/tourquise bar on the left of the company names

Comment: The results are retrieved from an Algolia search api. You could [replicate](https://pypi.org/project/algoliasearch/) the call and skip the scraping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a different approach than to simulate clicking all the buttons.
If you check the link of each start up base it is `https://startupbase.com.br/c/startup/` with start up base name separated by dashes
So you can use a base url

```
base_url = 'https://startupbase.com.br/c/startup/{}'
```

You can get the titles of every start up base using the following css selector `.org__title.sb-size-6`

```
titles = ['-'.join(title.text.split()) for title in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.org__title.sb-size-6')]
```

After that you can iterate through all titles and add its name after the base url, seperated by dashes instead of spaces

```
for title in titles:
    url = base_url.format(title)
```

And do whatever code you want to request using the url variable

Code:

```
base_url = 'https://startupbase.com.br/c/startup/{}'

titles = ['-'.join(title.text.split()) for title in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.org__title.sb-size-6')]

for title in titles:
    url = base_url.format(title)
```

Comment: There some names that doing this dont work.
To work I have to remove the seats and other things in the stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that easily using scrapy as api calls json response and following the post method.

CODE:

```
import scrapy
import json


class ScrollSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    
    body = '{"requests":[{"indexName":"prod_STARTUPBASE","params":"maxValuesPerFacet=100&query=&highlightPreTag=__ais-highlight__&highlightPostTag=__%2Fais-highlight__&page=0&facets=%5B%22segments.primary%22%2C%22state%22%2C%22place%22%2C%22business_target%22%2C%22business_phase%22%2C%22business_model%22%2C%22badges.name%22%5D&tagFilters=&facetFilters=%5B%5B%22segments.primary%3AConstru%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20Civil%22%2C%22segments.primary%3AImobili%C3%A1rio%22%5D%5D"},{"indexName":"prod_STARTUPBASE","params":"maxValuesPerFacet=100&query=&highlightPreTag=__ais-highlight__&highlightPostTag=__%2Fais-highlight__&page=0&hitsPerPage=1&attributesToRetrieve=%5B%5D&attributesToHighlight=%5B%5D&attributesToSnippet=%5B%5D&tagFilters=&analytics=false&clickAnalytics=false&facets=segments.primary"}]}'
    name = 'scroll'
    
    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(
            url= 'https://fwtbnxlfs6-3.algolianet.com/1/indexes/*/queries?x-algolia-agent=Algolia%20for%20JavaScript%20(3.35.1)%3B%20Browser%20(lite)%3B%20angular%20(9.0.7)%3B%20angular-instantsearch%20(3.0.0-beta.5)%3B%20instantsearch.js%20(4.7.0)%3B%20JS%20Helper%20(3.1.2)&x-algolia-application-id=FWTBNXLFS6&x-algolia-api-key=e5fef9eab51259b54d385c6f010cc399',
            callback = self.parse,
            method = 'POST',
            body = self.body,
            headers = {'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                       'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36'}
            )
        
    def parse(self, response):
        resp = json.loads(response.body)
        hits = resp['results'][0]['hits']
        
        for hit in hits:
            yield {
                'Name':hit['name']
                }
```

Output:

```
{'Name': 'Constr Up'}
2021-09-04 08:07:35 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://fwtbnxlfs6-3.algolianet.com/1/indexes/*/queries?x-algolia-agent=Algolia%20for%20JavaScript%20(3.35.1)%3B%20Browser%20(lite)%3B%20angular%20(9.0.7)%3B%20angular-instantsearch%20(3.0.0-beta.5)%3B%20instantsearch.js%20(4.7.0)%3B%20JS%20Helper%20(3.1.2)&x-algolia-application-id=FWTBNXLFS6&x-algolia-api-key=e5fef9eab51259b54d385c6f010cc399>
{'Name': 'Agenciou!'}
2021-09-04 08:07:35 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://fwtbnxlfs6-3.algolianet.com/1/indexes/*/queries?x-algolia-agent=Algolia%20for%20JavaScript%20(3.35.1)%3B%20Browser%20(lite)%3B%20angular%20(9.0.7)%3B%20angular-instantsearch%20(3.0.0-beta.5)%3B%20instantsearch.js%20(4.7.0)%3B%20JS%20Helper%20(3.1.2)&x-algolia-application-id=FWTBNXLFS6&x-algolia-api-key=e5fef9eab51259b54d385c6f010cc399>
{'Name': 'inQuality System'}
2021-09-04 08:07:35 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://fwtbnxlfs6-3.algolianet.com/1/indexes/*/queries?x-algolia-agent=Algolia%20for%20JavaScript%20(3.35.1)%3B%20Browser%20(lite)%3B%20angular%20(9.0.7)%3B%20angular-instantsearch%20(3.0.0-beta.5)%3B%20instantsearch.js%20(4.7.0)%3B%20JS%20Helper%20(3.1.2)&x-algolia-application-id=FWTBNXLFS6&x-algolia-api-key=e5fef9eab51259b54d385c6f010cc399>
{'Name': 'Constructweb - Gestão eficiente de reformas'}
2021-09-04 08:07:35 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://fwtbnxlfs6-3.algolianet.com/1/indexes/*/queries?x-algolia-agent=Algolia%20for%20JavaScript%20(3.35.1)%3B%20Browser%20(lite)%3B%20angular%20(9.0.7)%3B%20angular-instantsearch%20(3.0.0-beta.5)%3B%20instantsearch.js%20(4.7.0)%3B%20JS%20Helper%20(3.1.2)&x-algolia-application-id=FWTBNXLFS6&x-algolia-api-key=e5fef9eab51259b54d385c6f010cc399>
{'Name': 'Apê Fácil'}
2021-09-04 08:07:35 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://fwtbnxlfs6-3.algolianet.com/1/indexes/*/queries?x-algolia-agent=Algolia%20for%20JavaScript%20(3.35.1)%3B%20Browser%20(lite)%3B%20angular%20(9.0.7)%3B%20angular-instantsearch%20(3.0.0-beta.5)%3B%20instantsearch.js%20(4.7.0)%3B%20JS%20Helper%20(3.1.2)&x-algolia-application-id=FWTBNXLFS6&x-algolia-api-key=e5fef9eab51259b54d385c6f010cc399>
{'Name': 'Glück Imóveis '}
2021-09-04 08:07:35 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://fwtbnxlfs6-3.algolianet.com/1/indexes/*/queries?x-algolia-agent=Algolia%20for%20JavaScript%20(3.35.1)%3B%20Browser%20(lite)%3B%20angular%20(9.0.7)%3B%20angular-instantsearch%20(3.0.0-beta.5)%3B%20instantsearch.js%20(4.7.0)%3B%20JS%20Helper%20(3.1.2)&x-algolia-application-id=FWTBNXLFS6&x-algolia-api-key=e5fef9eab51259b54d385c6f010cc399>
{'Name': 'ArqColab'}
```

... so on

Response:

```
downloader/response_status_count/200
```

Answer (score 0):

Like I've said in the comment I made to your question. You are selecting the wrong element. You have to select the parent element of the `<a>` since this is what contains the action. You have to use xpath to get to the parent element.

```
internal_page = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/app-root/ng-component/app-layout/div/div/div/div/div/app-layout-column/ng-component/div/ais-instantsearch/div/div/div/div[2]/section/ais-infinite-hits/div/div[2]/a")

internal_page.find_element_by_xpath("./..").click()
```

Comment: I'm trying to make a for loop on this link, is it possible?

THE CODE OF THIS PART -> 
`for i in range(len(title_test)):
    k = (1 + i)
    print(k)
    internal_page = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/app-root/ng-component/app-layout/div/div/div/div/div/app-layout-column/ng-component/div/ais-instantsearch/div/div/div/div[2]/section/ais-infinite-hits/div/div[{}]/a".format(k))

    internal_page.find_element_by_xpath("./..").click()`